# Redirecting to xml file rather than R.java file

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I am using Mac(10.12.4) and I am using android Studio.Whenever I am pressing Command+Click on any R.layout.something it is redirecting on R.java file instead of the xml.

So can anyone please provide any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset your keymap of actions in this screen:

[image]

In your case, change the MAC OS Version, doing so, the reset button will be enable.

If it does not work, you can try File > Invalidade Caches/Restart

Comment: Thanks for the answer.How to go to the keymap?

Comment: In MAC, Click on Android Studio > Preferences > KeyMap

Comment: Found it and it is 10.5+ as yours screenshot.Do I need to change anything there?

Comment: it is right, probably is a garbage of Android Studio, Try to use a Invalidade Caches/Restart

Comment: Tried but same ):

Comment: Have you checked if the layout file exists?

Comment: Yes it is.I have checked.